# Identical values in one column and unique value pairs

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns

```
A      B
1      2
2      2
1      2
3      2
5      2
0      2
4      2
11     4
12     4
11     4
```

I want the SQL query to return the pairs (A,B) where:
B has appeared 3 or more times
AND (A,B) is unique

The resulting table would be:

```
A      B
1      2
2      2
3      2
5      2
0      2
4      2
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing very convincing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join with a selected  table grouped  by B having count = 3

```
select distinct A, B
from my_table as t1
inner join (
    select b 
    from my_table
    group by b
    having count(*)= 3
) t2 on t2.b = t1.b
```

and for 3 or more

```
select distinct A, B
from my_table as t1
inner join (
    select b 
    from my_table
    group by b
    having count(*) >= 3
) t2 on t2.b = t1.b
```

Comment: I think you want the having to be `having count(*)>=3` From question:
 (where: B has appeared 3 or more times )  oddly = 3 just returns {(11,4)(12,4)}

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I will need to make sense of this but it is really useful as i am a complete beginner